# c++ class object as function argument

Tags: c++

I am doing a c++ homework and I see a strange syntax:

```
class A{
private:
    string name;
public:
    A(string n) :name(n){}
    friend bool operator < (const class A& a1, const class A &a2);
}
```

There are `class` key words in the function `operator <`'s declaration.  I've never seen this before. Is this a good practice or we can just remove the `class` key word?

Comment: You can just remove it

Comment: I suspect, that it's the syntax inherited from C, where one would need to refer to `struct A {};` as `struct A a;`, unless `typedef`'ed. In C++ such syntax (`struct` in `struct A a;`) is optional. I suspect it's the same thing with `class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are legal and *normally* not required.

They are only required when there is *ambiguity* as to what `A` is.

For example:

```
#include <string>

extern void A();

class A
{
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    A(std::string n) :name(n){}
    friend bool operator < (const class A& a1, const class A &a2);
};

// removing `class` here would result in a compiler error as it would be
// ambiguous as to whether you meant the function A or the class A
bool operator < (const class A& a1, const class A &a2)
{
    return a1.name < a2.name;
};
```